# Formula for a range of numbers equals a number in a cell on a different sheet

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, nested-if

I am looking to do a formula in Excel to say a cell has a number inputted for example between 500-999 and it picks up a cost from a cell on another sheet.

so far I can only get 2 ranges to work using:

```
=If(C2<=999,Sheet1!H3,IF(C2>=1000,Sheet1!H4))
```

But if I do:

```
=If(C2<=999,Sheet1!H3,IF(C2>=1000,Sheet1!H4,IF(C2>=2000,Sheet1!H5)))
```

It still takes the value for >=1000

Any help on this will be grately appreicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the places of the conditions for `1000` and `2000`. Like this:

`=If(C2<=999,Sheet1!H3,IF(C2>=2000,Sheet1!H5,IF(C2>=1000,Sheet1!H4)))`

[In general, <kbd>F9</kbd> can do a wonderful job, when you are working with Excel formulas.](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Replace-a-formula-with-its-result-38001951-c0e8-4fbd-9048-37ef81e2891e)

Comment: Thank you so much! If I was to do ranges: 500-999 1000-1999 2000-2999 3000-4999 5000+ how would I write it?

Comment: @ScottPearce - reversed, starting from bigger than 5000, bigger than 3000, etc.

Comment: You legend! Thank you!

Comment: @ScottPearce - You welcome! :) In general, you can do the 500-999 1000-1999 thing, starting normally and checking whether it is smaller than 999, smaller than 1999 etc. Its a question of choice.